# How do i change Python 2d array elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mutable

```py
new = []
curvepoints = []   
for i in range (0, 10):
    for j in range (0, 3):
        new.append(0)
        curvepoints.append(new)
    new = []
```

I have initialized my main array `curvepoints` using the above code

```
p = [-30, -23, -16, -9, -2, 5, 12, 19, 30]
```

`p` is my 2nd array. I am trying to initialize every 1st element of `curvepoint` with element of `p` using the below code

```py
for i in range(0,len(p)):
    print(curvepoints[c][0])
    curvepoints[c][0]=p[i]
    c = c+1
```

But it is initializing abruptly as follows:

```
[[-16, 0, 0], [-16, 0, 0], [-16, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0], [30, 0, 0], [30, 0, 0], [30, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Please do let me know how I can initialize only the 1st elements with `p`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```py
p = [-30, -23, -16, -9, -2, 5, 12, 19, 30]
curvepoints = [[x, 0, 0] for x in p]
```

Which gives you:

```
[[-30, 0, 0], [-23, 0, 0], [-16, 0, 0], [-9, 0, 0], [-2, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0], [12, 0, 0], [19, 0, 0], [30, 0, 0]]
```